# Trouble with angularjs animations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

```
Module.animation 'slide-down', ($rootScope) ->
      console.log 'animationInit'
      animation =
        setup: () ->
        start: (element, done, memo) ->
          $(element).slideDown()
          console.log 'animationrun'
```

---

```
<div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:0;" class="alert alert-error" data-ng-show="errorMessage" data-ng-animate="{enter: 'slide-down'}">
    <strong>Error!</strong><br/><span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
</div>
```

---

I'm trying to get the above div to slide-down when shown in angularjs, however it's not working for some reason.

In my console I see 'animationInit' when my page loads.

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngShow` and `ngHide` support the `show` and `hide` keys of `ngAnimate`, not `enter`; also, don't forget to call `done` in the `start` function so Angular knows when the animation is done.

```
Module.animation "slide-down", ->
  setup: (element) ->
    element.css(display: "none")

  start: (element, done, memo) ->
    element.slideDown(done)
```

- Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/CcwKz/
- CoffeeScript on CodePen: http://codepen.io/BinaryMuse/pen/nCIfD